# Firefox 26 utf-8 encoding issues in facebook pagetab app

Tags: html, facebook, firefox, cross-browser

I am experiencing a very strange bug after updating my firefox to version 26 (on macbook pro with mountain lion).  Although the headers have not changed, it is now failing to encode the utf-8 characters correctly.  I tried several different header styles but still end up with the same problem:

My original header is somewhat old-school but it is working fine in every other browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Even stranger is the fact that if I run the page tab app directly via its server url (outside of facebook and its pagetab iframe) the encoding works fine!!

I tried the strict doctype and html5 doctype tags, but the problem still remains!

If anyone has any ideas about whats going on I would be appreciate hearing them.

Comment: What charset is your server indicating via _HTTP_ headers (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least latest version of Firefox(26.0) complaints in console if you have too much stuff before introducing charset meta tag.

> The character encoding declaration of document was found too late for
>   it to take effect. The encoding declaration needs to be moved to be
>   within the first 1024 bytes of the file.

So it could help if you move charset declaration right after opening  -tag.

Comment: That was it. The framework I am using was injecting content in the header before the utf-8 meta tag